# How can I look at time while using mac all the times?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am very new to Mac and I have always been a windows user and one thing that I love about windows(which I did not realize/appreciate until I started using Mac) is that I can look at what time it is right now at any point regardless of what I am doing with  PC at this time. I think that is because of its ever-present status bar. With mac, I do not have that luxury at all. I am just trying to figure out if there is a way to know what time is it while using Mac?

Comment: As you say you are new to the mac then you may benefit from articles such as this ine explaining how to do things : https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-move-from-pc-mac-3620931/?p=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to system preferences under the apple menu there is a icon for date and time about four rows down, click on date and time. In date and time click on the Clock tab and click on 'show date and time in menu bar'. This puts a clock in the menu bar. You can choose between analog clock or digital.

Comment: Well, yes that works in general situations. However, whenever any APP is open in full screen and I want to check the time, it seems like I cannot because the app takes the entire screen and the only way for me to check the time at that point is when I minimize the window and look at the menubar. Unlike windows, where I can look at time anytime :)

Comment: @TeaLeave, All you have to do when a window is full screen is to move the mouse to the top of the screen and the Menubar will appear, then you can then see the clock.